# Import emojicon Library Into Android Studio

Tags: android

https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon

How do I add this library into Android Studio so that I can use it in my project. 
Usually I add a line into my build.gradle file?

Comment: The repository has a demo project: https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/tree/master/example. Overall, you're question is too broad and denotes a lack of research.

Comment: Import the library project into android studio. Then right click on your project and open module settings. Click on the module app on the left and go to the  dependencies tab. Add the library project as a dependency. Or ou can also use this lib https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon/, simply adding a line to your gradle fie.

Comment: When adding the library project as a dependency is it a library, file or module dependency? I tried the project you suggested at first but it didn't meet my needs.

Comment: @andryr I just found this link https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/issues/2 Is it possible without having to install eclipse?

Comment: @shkschneider I fail to see how the demo project will help me? https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/issues/2 Is it possible without having to install eclipse?

Comment: There is no Gradle build available for this project. But the `lib` folder can still be loaded in Android Studio as a module: it contains `res` with icons and Java source code.

Answer (score 7):

I had faced same problem recently. I know it is too late to answer this. However, I am still sharing my findings in case if someone finds it useful in future:

1. Download 'emojicon':

   Download source from [here](https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon). Lets say you've downloaded it in `D:\Emojicon`
2. Import library `D:\Emojicon\lib` to your project:

   In Android Studio go to File->Project Structure then click on '+' symbol. From the dialog box pops up choose appropriate option to import library. 
   (For e.g. on my system I have Android Studio 2.1.2, it shows me "Create New Module" dialog then I choose "Import Eclipse EDT Project")

   Then select `D:\emojicon\lib` to import emojion library to your project. It will copy emojicon project to your project.
3. Set dependency:

   Then click on Dependencies tab (in dialog options box from File->Project Structure). From the list that appears on left side, click on your project under modules.
   You will see all your project dependencies. Now click on '+' symbol from top right corner and select "Module dependency". The dialog next will show "lib" as module. Just select that and click OK to close dialog. Close Project Structure dialog also. That's it! You have successfully imported emojicon library and have set its dependency.
4. Implement:

   Now refer [example](https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/tree/master/example) project to see how to use emojicon in your project (Its basically using EmojiconEditText and EmojiconEditView instead of EditText and TextView)

Comment: there is problem with this lib emoji's keyboard height width not according to softkeyboard there is little margin from all sides can you please tell me what is wrong?