# How to access Google Keyboard Default smiley or emoji?

Tags: android, keyboard, emoji

I am working on a chat application, in my chat screen I have smiley image on click of which I want to access keyboards default smileys. Is there any way to achieve this?

This is my screen with smiley icon[image]

I want this popup on smiley icon key[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768930/implementations-of-emoji-emoticon-view-keyboard-layouts

Comment: can you provide more precise solution... i don't want to use any library, is there any way to access above smiley popup?

Comment: for this you have to create a custom grid view..And have to use hashmap to replace text with the image , plus you have to write a code to show your image in textview.

Comment: use this lib to reduce your work 
https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon
If you want to do it your self..I just told how to do it..

Comment: there was no complie gradle code for this library

Comment: download and import it as a library project