# How to Add Feeling excited, Reading, Watching, etc in publish post using Facebook android SDK?

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.x

Is it possible to publish post to user's wall with " - feeling excited,  reading, watching", etc using facebook android SDK? I search in the documentations but didn't find any way to do that.

I am posting the status this way:

```
mFacebookCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "in LoginResult on success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            /* make the photo share call */
            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
            postParams.putString("name", "test data");
            new GraphRequest( AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                  "/me/photos",  //photos
                  postParams,
                  HttpMethod.POST,
                  new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                  public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully share post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                    }
            ).executeAsync();
      }
};
```

Does anybody know of a way?

Answer (score 1):

Finally i have found a solution .There's no API for the emotions. But  I found a very useful [Emoticon Keyboard](https://github.com/chiragjain/Emoticons-Keyboard). This keyboard is not using Unicode sequences but rather just local image assets.
Using [Supported Unicode Sequences](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode#note1) as well as the [Visual Unicode Database](http://www.charbase.com/1F601) we can set Unicode representation of [image], is '\ud83d\ude03' and this code can be added to our post status like :

```
EditText messageInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
messageInput.getText().append("\ud83d\ude03");
```

So I can add emotion to my facebook post as like:

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("message", shareEditText.getText().append("\ud83d\ude01").toString());
```

this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768930/implementations-of-emoji-emoticon-view-keyboard-layouts) is helpful.