# Android keyboard with text input disable [Emoji's keyboard only]

Tags: java, android, keyboard, emoji

I want to use a keyboard with the text input option disable, is there another option than creating a new keyboard without text option? Maybe not using EditText or an Android Studio setting to disable text input and still using android:inputType emojis?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768930/implementations-of-emoji-emoticon-view-keyboard-layouts

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `EditText` attributes?

```
android:inputType="textShortMessage"
```

Comment: With -android:inputType="textPersonName"- i display text and icon keyboard the user get as default but i want to display only the icon/emoji one.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible as far as I can see. You just can change some parts by `inputType`. If you want a specific keyboard, try to implement **Emoji Keyboard** using fragments.

There is an example : [Emojicon](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon)