# Android enable only emoji in keyboard

Tags: android, emoji

We wanted to enable the emoji as default in our android app. That is, when a user try to type something, the keyboard should popup with emojis by default. What is the configurations done in `xml` or `activity.java` files?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768930/implementations-of-emoji-emoticon-view-keyboard-layouts

Answer (score 0):

using the answer here `EditText messageInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_input);
messageInput.getText().append("\ud83d\ude01");` reference [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17014940/3321991)

or you can use one of the libraries [emoji](https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji)

or this [super-nova](https://github.com/hani-momanii/SuperNova-Emoji)