# How to display emoji keyboard when click on emoji key key in android custom keyboard?

Tags: android

I have done all the functionalities which are necessary for an android keyboard. But now I am stuck that how to display emoji when user clicks on emoji key. Please help me how to do it.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768930/implementations-of-emoji-emoticon-view-keyboard-layouts?noredirect=1&lq=1